# How to sort an array and a matrix together using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `y` and a matrix `X` that is CSR sparse.

I need to do a random sort of `y` and X where each row of `y` corresponds to a row in `X`.

Using NumPy, how do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'random sort'? Randomly shuffling the items of the array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a random sort, you could try to use the `np.random.shuffle` function.

```
# Create an array of indices
indices = np.arange(y.size)
# Randomize it
np.random.shuffle(indices)
```

You can now use `indices` to randomize `y` with fancy indexing `y_new = y[indices]`.

You could use the same `indices` to reorder your matrix, but be careful, CSR matrices don't support fancy indexing. You'll have to transform it to LIL, reorder it, then retransform it to CSR.