# Mask an array by value then mask the corresponding Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array y [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]

Then I have a matrix X that is numpy csr format.

1) I need to mask element 6 in y. Then, I need to mask the corresponding row in X.

So, y.shape is 12.  Should be 10.  The X is 12,20.  Should be 10,20.

How do I do this in numpy

Answer (score 1):

If your 'masked' output `y` should be smaller than your input, you're not really using masks.

As suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150669/how-to-sort-an-array-and-a-matrix-together-using-numpy), you can really easily find the indices for which `y` is different from 6

```
condition = (y != 6)
```

That's abool array that you can use to retrieve the values of `y` that are not 6

```
y = y[condition]
```

You could use the same `condition` to get the corresponding lines of `X`, except that it's CSR and therefore doesn't support fancy index formatting. You could still transform it to LIL then back.

You could also get the indices for which `y !=6` with

```
(indices,) = np.nonzero(y != 6)
```

It's a regular integer array that you can use to index your `X`.

Comment: Do I not the index for a csr rather a bool?  Can I get the indexes of the filered out Y values and use to filter for X crs?

Comment: You don't really need the indices, you can just directly index with a boolean array. If you really want the indices, you can use `np.nonzero(y!=6)`, but you'll still be using fancy indexing that your `X` matrix won't support...

Comment: My X is (14259, 50042) too big to fit in ram.

Comment: @Tampa, you should be able to index X[rows] if its CSR. however it must not be a boolean array, so use np.where first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like answering my own questions but the proper solution is this for dealing with a csr matrix:

```
X = X[np.where(y != 6)[0]]
y = y[y != 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but maybe this will be helpful:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(range(1,7)*2)  #Your array.
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> b = np.array(list(a)*20).reshape(12,20) #just some matrix of right size and shape. np.empty(12,20) would probably work just as well.
>>> b
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])


>>> mask = a != 6 #mask.  True for all points except ones where value == 6.
>>> b[mask,:]   #take points along first axis where mask==True, all points along second axis.
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html).

(Assuming x is defined already)

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6])
keepers = np.nonzero(y != 6)
y = y[keepers]
x = x[keepers, :]
```

Comment: I missed where you said that your matrix is CSR.  Not sure if this works for that, but give it a shot, I suppose...